# Interaction SQL Server Developer edition with production environment

Tags: sql-server, licensing

Could I read data from production environment by using SQL Server developer edition?
Maybe exist some licensing restrictions about that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, there is nothing to stop you. As far as I know is the Developer Edition just different in the *not for production purposes* statement. It is actually a Enterprise Edition.

If the license allows it? Presumably not if you use it for production purposes. If you use it as part of your development process, it probably is allowed.